# Why do I leak memory in EOutOfResources?

Tags: delphi, jpeg, delphi-10.3-rio

I try to implement a wrapper around [this](http://www.marktg.com/jpegdec/) jpeg decoder library (original by Arnaud Bouchez).  The library is DAMN fast but it does not support all jpegs!

For very large jpg files it fails (as expected) with a EOutOfResources exception.
So I try to silently skip those files. It works, but when I close the app, FastMM indicates a memory leak.

```
function FastJpgDecode(FileName: string; OUT ErrorType: string): TBitmap;
var Img: PJpegDecode;
    res: TJpegDecodeError;
    Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result:= NIL;
  Stream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  TRY
    if Length(FileName) > MAX_PATH then { TMemoryStream does not support long paths }
     begin
      ErrorType:= 'File name too long!';
      Exit;
     end;

    Stream.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    Stream.Position:= 0;
    res:= JpegDecode(Stream.Memory, Stream.Size, Img);       
    case res of
     JPEG_SUCCESS:
      begin
       try
        Result:= Img.ToBitmap; // This will raise an EOutOfResources for large files!
       except
        on EOutOfResources do
          ErrorType:= 'JPEG_OUTOFMEM!';
       end;
      end;

     JPEG_EOF                : ErrorType:= 'JPEG_EOF!';
     JPEG_OUTOFMEM           : ErrorType:= 'JPEG_OUTOFMEM!';
     JPEG_CPUNOTSUPPORTED    : ErrorType:= 'JPEG_CPUNOTSUPPORTED!';
     JPEG_BADFILE            : ErrorType:= 'JPEG_BADFILE!';
     JPEG_FORMATNOTSUPPORTED : ErrorType:= 'JPEG_FORMATNOTSUPPORTED!';       // Not all jpegs are supported. In this case we fall back to WIC or the standard LoadGraph loader (WIC).   
    end;
  FINALLY
    Img.Free;
    Stream.Free;
  END;
end;



function TJpegDecode.ToBitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  if @self=nil
  then result := nil
  else
   begin
    result := TBitmap.Create;
    try
     if not ToBitmap(result)   // This will raise an EOutOfResources for large files!
     then FreeAndNil(result);
    except
      FreeAndNil(Result);
      raise;
    end;
   end;
end;
```

> A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 36
>
> This block was allocated by thread 0xD0C, and the stack trace (return
>   addresses) at the time was: 407246  40830F  408ADE  43231B [Unknown
>   function at __dbk_fcall_wrapper] 407246  40A532  53C353 [Unknown
>   function at TMethodImplementationIntercept] 6E006F [Unknown function
>   at TMethodImplementationIntercept] 7765648F [RtlNtStatusToDosError]
>   77656494 [RtlNtStatusToDosError] 767A7BEA [Unknown function at
>   IsNLSDefinedString]
>
> The block is currently used for an object of class: EOutOfResources
>   The allocation number is: 4181
>
> Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7EEEA6C0:
>   74 7F............  t    D  .  ü  $  ú ......
>
> A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 132
>   This block was allocated by thread 0xD0C, and the stack trace (return
>   addresses) at the time was: 407246  40A2E7  40A518  53C341 [Unknown
>   function at TMethodImplementationIntercept] 6E006F [Unknown function
>   at TMethodImplementationIntercept] 7765648F [RtlNtStatusToDosError]
>   77656494 [RtlNtStatusToDosError] 767A7BEA [Unknown function at
>   IsNLSDefinedString] 7677F0BA [VirtualQueryEx] 7677F177 [VirtualQuery]
>   898FD9 [GetFrameBasedStackTrace]
>
> The block is currently used for an object of class: UnicodeString
>
> The allocation number is: 4180
>
> Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7EFA24F0:
>   B0 04 02 00 01 00 00 00.........
>    .  .  .  .  .  .  .  :  .  .  .  Not  .     .  enough storage  .     .  i  .  s  .     .  a  .  v  .  a  .  i  . l  .  a  .  b 
>   .  l  .  e  .     .  t  .  o  .     .  p  .  r  .  o  .  c  .  e  .  s
>   .  s  .    .  t  .  h  .  i  .  s  .     .  c  .  o  .  m  .  m  .  a 
>   .  n  .  d  ............
>
> This application has leaked
>   memory. The small block leaks are (excluding expected leaks registered
>   by pointer):
>
> 21 - 36 bytes: EOutOfResources x 1 
>   117 - 132 bytes: UnicodeString x 1

Why does it leak memory there?

Comment: Looks a bit like data for an exception/error return that ends up getting orphaned.

Comment: `EOutOfMemory` - very special exception. It contains private flag `AllowFree` (False by default). This flag prevent created exception from normal freeing. See `EHeapException.FreeInstance`. This is "normal" because this exception raised when  "normal" memory management fails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @kami mentioned in comments, `EHeapException` has an internal `AllowFree` flag that is False by default, preventing instances of `EHeapException` from being freed by exception handlers.

`EOutOfResources` derives from `EOutOfMemory`, which in turn derives from `EHeapException`.

The `SysUtils` unit has 2 singleton objects of type `EOutOfMemory` and `EInvalidPointer`.  Whenever the RTL raises those two specific exception types directly, it raises the *same instance* of those classes every time. So they have an `AllowFree` flag to prevent exception handlers from freeing the singletons.  The singletons are freed when the `SysUtils` unit is finalized.

This is actually documented behavior:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.EHeapException

> Note: Memory for these exceptions is pre-allocated whenever an application starts and remains allocated as long as the application is running. Never raise `EHeapException` **or its descendants** directly.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.EOutOfMemory

> Memory for the `EOutOfMemory` exception is pre-allocated whenever an application starts and remains allocated as long as the application is running.
>
> Note: Never raise `EOutOfMemory` directly. Instead, call the global `OutOfMemoryError` procedure.

However, although `EOutOfResources` derives from `EHeapException`, it is never used in a singleton manner, so its `AllowFree` flag really should never be False.  So it seems to me that there are several bugs at play here:

- `EOutOfResources` is not really a heap error and should not have been derived from `EHeapException` to begin with.  It is actually a common exception, for instance the `Vcl.Graphics` unit raises `EOutOfResources` for some of its GDI errors, which have nothing to do with the heap.
- `EOutOfResources` has its `AllowFree` flag set to False when it should be True instead. And the flag is `private`, so it can't be overwritten except by the `SysUtils` unit, which does so only for the 2 singletons during finalization.  So basically, *all* `EHeapException`-derived exceptions get leaked at runtime.
- the singletons, as well as all other descendant instances, are not passed to the RTL's `RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak()` function when `AllowFree` is False so they can be omitted from leak reports.

This leak issue has existed since Delphi 5, and has already been reported to Embarcadero:

[RSP-17193: EOutOfResources memory leak](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17193)

[RSP-19737: EOutOfResources exception causes memory leak](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19737)